# How would I use a friend method that is predefined in a header file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header-files, friend

Essentially, my Computer Science teacher is making me use the friend std::ostream method for output.. I have imported it into the header file as one can see below, but I have no clue how to use it in the student.cpp. Adding student::ostream did not work. How would I be able to use the header predefined method in my student.cpp

My header file

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class student
{
public:
    student();
    std::string settingStudentName;
    bool disiplineIssue();

    // provided again so you learn this valuable override method for printing class data.
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& const student &);

private:
    std::string studentName;
    bool hasDisciplineIssue;
};
```

Student.cpp

```
#include "student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

student::student()
{
    
}


bool student::disiplineIssue()
{
    // Max the random integer can go
   int max = 100;
   srand(time(0));
   int random = rand()%max;

    // bool variable for returning
    bool True_or_False = false;
   if (random <= 5)
   {
       True_or_False = true;
   }
   return True_or_False;    
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, const student& aStudent) {
    
    output << aStudent.studentName << " ";
    if (aStudent.hasDisciplineIssue) {
        output << "has ";
    }
    else {
        output << "doesn't have ";
    }
    output << "a discipline issue";
    return output;
}
```

Edit:
When I do not have student:: in front, ostream works but if I add student:: in front, it says it can not resolve the symbol. I am not sure if the one without student:: is using the one I defined in the header file.

Comment: What is your question? You seem to already have all the code in place.

Comment: You have a correct implementation in your `student.cpp`, where do you want to use it? You'd probably want to use it outside of the class, for example `Student s; std::cout << s;`

Comment: @SergeyA I can't figure out how to use the predefined output method that I defined in my header file. I will add screenshots for clarity.

Comment: Don't you need a comma between the parameters in the header file declaration?

Comment: What is the error message you get from the compiler? As already mean ruined there is a missing comma in the header.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen
I have the Boolean method to generate a 5% chance if their is a disciplinary issue or not. If there is, it returns true, and if not false. The ostream method is supposed to output has or doesn't have a discipline issue based on if its true or false.

Comment: Also I notice that the function `disciplineIssue` doesn't actually have any relationship to the `hasDisciplineIssue` member variable. I don't know exactly which parts of this code were provided by the instructor and which were written by you but that'll probably be an issue. Similarly I'm not sure what the connection is supposed to be between `settingStudentName` and `studentName`.

Comment: @NathanPierson
I added a comma in my header file declaration, and it still did not fix my ostream error. If I do not have student::, ostream works. I add student::, ostream says that it can not resolve symbol. Do I need the student:: in the front?

Comment: @RohanParikh No, there should be no `student::` in the definition. `friend` function is not a class member, even though it can be declared in class definition. It's a free function. And it must be this way, otherwise any operator overload would require class instance as first argument, which means you would need to write `student s; s << std::cout;`, and that would mess up absolutely everyone who read your code.

Comment: No. It's not a member function of the `student` class, it's a free function. Your problem is that the rest of your `student` class isn't doing the things you expect.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen
That solved my issue! Thanks for your help despite my unclear question.

Comment: `friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& const student &);` does not define a function. The `friend` keyword means, that the function with the signature after that keywords is allowed to access private and protected members of the class in with the `friend` statement is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would proceed in the following manner:

1. add body and declaration parameters to function `settingStudentName` in both header and main file;
2. insert correct dependancies (`#include`);
3. add a `main()` driver function;
4. also, use correct syntax (`friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const student &);`) lacked the comma `,` separator between the function arguments.

A MWE:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H_INCLUDED
#define STUDENT_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class student
{
public:
    student();
    std::string settingStudentName(const std::string&);
    bool disiplineIssue();

    // provided again so you learn this valuable override method for printing class data.
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const student &);

private:
    std::string studentName;
    bool hasDisciplineIssue;
};

#endif // STUDENT_H_INCLUDED
```

```
#include "student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

student::student()
{

}

string student::settingStudentName(const string& input)
{
    studentName = input;

    return input;
}

bool student::disiplineIssue()
{
    // Max the random integer can go
   int max = 100;
   srand(time(0));
   int random = rand()%max;

    // bool variable for returning
    bool True_or_False = false;
   if (random <= 5)
   {
       True_or_False = true;
   }
   return True_or_False;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, const student& aStudent) {

    output << aStudent.studentName << " ";
    if (aStudent.hasDisciplineIssue) {
        output << "has ";
    }
    else {
        output << "doesn't have ";
    }
    output << "a discipline issue";
    return output;
}


int main()
{
    student Jack;
    Jack.settingStudentName("Jack");
    Jack.disiplineIssue();

    cout << Jack << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Jack has a discipline issue
```

And here is a compiled version you can play with https://wandbox.org/permlink/mF49xQxkXs3M7n0M

Comment: `1. add function settingStudentName in both header and main file` why is that relevant for the problem of the question?

Comment: @t.niese Because otherwise the program would just print "has a discipline issue"

Comment: This was helpful, thanks! I don't think the main method is needed though since I have another file called main.cpp, correct. I just need to have the contents of the method in that file.